# How to keep reference to mail after sending in Outlook VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook-addin

I'm using outlook to send e-mails (from Excel VBA)

```
With OutlookApplication.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  .Subject = topic
  .to = emailAddress
  .HTMLBody = content
  .Send
  msgbox .Sent
end with
```

`msgbox .Sent` raises error. It looks like reference to mail dies after sending.
Is there any way to check .sent or .sentOn parameters after sending mail?

Answer (score 1):

The `Sent` property can be checked when an item is added to the `Sent Items` folder (i.e. sent). You can hook up to the `ItemAdd` event of the `Sent Items` folder and check the `Sent` property there.

Note, the `Send` method may fire an exception when you try to automate Outlook. In this case most probably you are faced with an Outlook security issue. It can also be a prompt issued by Outlook if you try to access any protected property or method. But in your case that is an exception. You get the security prompts/exceptions because Outlook is configured on the client computer in one of the following ways:

- Uses the default Outlook security settings (that is, no Group Policy set up)
- Uses security settings defined by Group Policy but does not have programmatic access policy applied
- Uses security settings defined by Group Policy which is set to warn when the antivirus software is inactive or out of date

You can create a group policy to prevent security prompts from displaying if any up-to-date antivirus software is installed on the system or just turn these warning off (which is not really recommended).

Read more about that in the [Security Behavior of the Outlook Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/How-to/Security/security-behavior-of-the-outlook-object-model) article.

Also you may consider using a low-level code on which Outlook is built and which doesn't give security issues - Extended MAPI. Consider using any third-party wrappers around that API such as [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption).

Another option would be the [Outlook Security Manager](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) which allows suppressing Outlook security issues at runtime on the fly.