# How does the mailItem.sent parameter work?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm sending mails using Excel VBA:

```vb
With OutlookApplication.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    .Subject = topic
    .to = emailAddress
    .HTMLBody = content
    .Send
    msgbox .Sent
end with
```

where `.Sent` raises an error on my computer.

I asked why:
[How to keep reference to mail after sending in Outlook VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855171/how-to-keep-reference-to-mail-after-sending-in-outlook-vba)

I decided to ignore that error and assume that email reference disappears   after sending.

Now a client reported that `.Send` returns `False`, when email was sent.

Why does `.Sent` lie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only allowed operation after you call `MailItem.Send` is to release your reference to the `MailItem` variable.

Even if you could do that, `Sent` property would still be false: message submission is an asynchronous process. Outlook moves the message to the Outbox folder, and hands it over to the transport provider. Once it asynchronously sends the message, a new message is created in the Sent Items folder with all sender related properties populated. That (new) message will have the `Sent` property as true.